# Append login and note/comment in one page, single click action?

Tags: html, forms, authentication, asp-classic

I have saved two pages evernote.com/mobile/Login.action and http://www.evernote.com/mobile/CreateNote.action?paginatedQuery.page=0&paginatedQuery.queryDefinition=RECENT%3A locally and want to create a single page for logging-in and creating note.
Login page has this code-

```
<div id="pageContent">
  <div id="login_box">
  <div id="login_header">< 
 style="margin: 
4px;" /><br />
  </div>
  <div id="login_form">



<form action="https://www.evernote.com/mobile/Login.action" 
method="post">

 Username:<br />
 <input type="text" maxlength="128" style="" name="username" 
value="" />
 <br />

 Password:<br />
 <input type="password" style="" name="password" />
 <br />


 <label> </label>:<input type="checkbox" 
name="rememberMe"  />
 <br />

 <input type="hidden" name="targetUrl" value="https://www.evernote.com/mobile/CreateNote.action?paginatedQuery.page=0&paginatedQuery.queryDefinition=RECENT%3A" />
 <input type="hidden" name="if" value="" />
 <input type="submit" name="login" value="Sign in" />
<div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="_sourcePage" 
value="6Gq5oyoJK3_iMUD9T65RG6N9IohKa-1u4T_VcvCojVY=" /><input 
type="hidden" name="__fp" value="LC0Qh2apg0U3yWPvuidLz-TPR6I9Jhx8" /></div></form>
```

and add Note page has following code-

```
<!-- CONTENT -->
  <div id="pageContent">
   <div class="pagetitle_box">
    <h2>Quick Note</h2>

   </div>

    <!-- NOTE FORM -->
    <div class="normal_box formList">

    <form style="margin: 2px;" name="add_note" action="https://www.evernote.com/mobile/CreateNote.action" method="post">

      Title:<br />
      <input maxlength="128" style="" name="title" type="text" size="16" />
      <br />
      Body:<br />




      <textarea cols="14" style="" name="body" rows="4"></textarea>
      <br />
      Tags:<br />
      <input size="16" name="tags" maxlength="128" style="" />
      <br />



          <input name="notebookGuid" value="76b3cff2-ffdb-4680-852e-56ccace3cacb" type="hidden" />



      <input name="createNote" value="Save" type="submit" />
    <div style="display: none;"><input type="hidden" name="_sourcePage" value="I3PtAi9_njziMUD9T65RGzEFk2Nb44RKS-4UoK3vnv0=" /><input type="hidden" name="__fp" value="Vn2P_ij96x0=" /></div></form>

    </div> <!-- end normal_box -->
    <!-- END NOTE FORM -->
    <br />
  </div>
  <!-- END CONTENT -->
```

how can I merge these two codes in a single page to login and post note with a single-click after filling all forms?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this. You can't simply save html source and make it work.

The simplest way is to use [Evernote API](http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/), create your own site, design page as you like and implement API calls to login and send note in one time.